# Golang convert simple code array to string

Tags: arrays, string, go

How to convert simple code array to string

```golang
a := []int{1,2,3}
ayam := "bebek" + a
fmt.Print(ayam)
```

example

```
[1,2,3]  => "[1,2,3]"
```

a (mismatched types string and []int)

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go (once more) and take a look at fmt.Sprintf and the %v verb.

Comment: You cannot add strings and integer slices (or anything else except strings, really). What do you expect the result of that to be?

Comment: Also note that `[]int` is a slice and not an array.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/list

Comment: go !====== javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use `json.Marshal()`.

```
a := []int{1,2,3}
s, _ := json.Marshal(a)
// s should be "[1, 2, 3]"
```